# My game got stolen, what do I do?

Tags: legal, google-play, distribution

I recently released my first game on the Google Play Store (yay!), and a few days later I found my game had been reuploaded to two different shady-looking sites (Softonic and Fibonapps). Needless to say, I did not give either of these sites permission to distribute my game. It is a paid app, so if people download it from these other sites I'm effectively losing money. I sent an email to both about two weeks ago asking them to remove it, I've gotten no response and the listings are still up. How do I proceed from here?

Comment: Basically.... get a lawyer.  Assuming you desire to make money from your game, this is losing you money and the investment in a lawyer will be necessary to help you reach this goal.

Comment: Are the copied games available on Play Store, or do the sites provide them as files to download? It is limited how many that download and manually install apps, and the overlap between those that manually install apps and pay for apps is probably small

Answer (score 3):

The same thing has happened to me in the past. Here are a few things I learnt from it.

Remember if they distribute your game it's not ideal, however you primarily lose out on ratings and publicity on the official play store. If you release games with ads or in app purchases then you should be covered in some sense for your revenue.

I emailed each website and gave them a notice of legal action if they don't remove it. 9/10 times they remove it as they know their site is dodgy but don't want the hassle from a developer.

Sometimes it's hard to find the email so use whois.com and see what you can find on the domain to locate someone to contact.

Answer (score 1):

Those sites are potentially guilty of ip/copyright theft and software piracy.

Speak to a lawyer who is a specialist in Intellectual Property with regards to software.

If you agree to the fees, they will investigate on your behalf, and, if warranted, will send a "cease and desist" letter, and/or notify the relevant authorities of software piracy. What happens after that is up to the authorities/courts.

But honestly, this is a widespread problem, and not easily dealt with.

You may wish to consider some form of digital rights management, or "DRM", but that tends to have a bit of a bad reputation these days, so make sure you are aware of *all* your options.