# Can I report someone for cloning my game?

Tags: ios

I recently found out that someone cloned my game from 2018 (2d, pixel art, here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fiTJn5PULnA) that was on iOS, made it in 3d for android (here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.goquest.angrywife). Copied name, mechanics, everything, even some of the optional gadgets.

I paused my apple dev subscription at the end of 2019 so my game is not available for download anymore, but this guy released it in mid 2019, when it was.

I was wondering if I can somehow take action and have google remove the game from the listing.

Comment: Related: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/177857/my-game-got-stolen-what-do-i-do

Comment: Also related: [How closely can a game legally resemble another?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1653/how-closely-can-a-game-legally-resemble-another) (basically the same question, just asked from the opposite perspective)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this would be from futile to impossible. Unfortunately it's quite common to see clones of other games. Unless that person is using exact copies of your assets from your game this game won't be considered "stolen".

You can try to lawyer up, but consider amount of clones out there, even with same name, but released on different platform.